# Уникальный идентификатор Android устройства

Tags: java, android

После API level 29 на гугладевайсах нельзя получить IMEI средствами TelephonyManager.getImei без рута. Есть достойная (АППАРАТНАЯ) альтернатива IMEI или законный способ получить его?
В качестве альтернативы, конечно, можно использовать GUID, Android_ID и т.п., но эти номера изменяемые после переустановки приложения или сброса настроек устройства. Единственный вариант на который можно обратить внимание - MAC адрес, но и его можно подменить в настройках системы.

Comment: `ANDROID_ID: The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device or if an APK signing key changes.` Простая переустановка приложения не влияет. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID

Comment: Всё верно - аппарат сбросили к заводским настройкам - концов не найдёшь, с какого устройства выполнена операция. В моём случае - это очень вероятно.

Comment: А не надо концы искать. Надо делать так, чтобы этого не требовалось. Если мне (пользователю) надо я подменю любой идентификатор если не в системе, то в вашем приложении или подделаю запросы, которые оно посылает (если речь о получении данных с сервера)

Comment: @woesss, Приложение для нужд не публичной сети. Едва ли рядовой сотрудник будет что-то подменять на устройстве. Вот что бы не занимается поиском от кого что пришло и хотел использовать imei. Да и речь не о вредительстве и обмане.

Comment: Тогда почему не аутентификация? Сотрудник сам вводит какие-то данные, которые идентифицируют его, приложение запоминает и работает. Мне думается это проще, чем добывать у каждого IMEI, чтобы занести его в базу, ещё при смене аппарата повторять процедуру.

Comment: Есть аутентификация, просто нужна привязка пользователя к конкретному смартфону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ANDROID_ID - единственный вариант, то

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: На данный момент ничего лучшего не предлагается. https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids